# ¿Cómo actualizar un campo con valor null en SpringBoot jpa?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-boot, jpa

Estoy realizando un Update con diferentes campos, y a la hora de mandar un valor null al campo **FECHA** el cual es de tipo Date manda el siguiente mensaje de error , y el campo si es Nullable en mi base de datos Oracle

> 2023-05-02 15:21:25.358  WARN 20940 --- [nio-8080-exec-3]
> o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 932, SQLState:
> 42000 2023-05-02 15:21:25.358 ERROR 20940 --- [nio-8080-exec-3]
> o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-00932: tipos de dato
> inconsistentes: se esperaba DATE se ha obtenido BINARY

este es mi Query

```
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "UPDATE CONTROL C SET CVE_ESTADO=?1, HORA=?2, FECHA=?3 WHERE C.ID=?4", nativeQuery = true)
    void updateCampos(String cveEstado, String hora, Date fecha, String id);
```

Mi servicio

```
    @Override
    public void update(ControlEntity entidad, String id) {
        try {
            repository.updateControlbyId(entidad.getCveEstado(), entidad.getHora(), null, id);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("An error ocurred looking for Data");

        }

    }
```

Controller

```
 @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public void actualizar(@RequestBody ControlEntity entidad,  @PathVariable("id") String id) throws Exception {
        try {
            controlService.update(entidad, id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error in ExecutionControlEntity Values ");
            throw e;
        }

    }
```

qué tengo que cambiar para que cuando inserte null no tenga problema?
puede que al hacer el update solo se actualice un campo, y los demas se queden con el mismo valor

UPDATE

agrego la entidad

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTROL)
public class ControlEntity implements Serializable {

    /**
     * Serial version
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "CVE_ESTADO")
    private String cveEstado;

    @Column(name = "HORA")
    private String hora;

    @Column(name = "FECHA")
    private Date fecha;


}
```

Comment: Podrías compartir como está  definida tu clase Entity, puede deberse a serialización y adicional como está definida tu columna en Oracle.

Comment: @Ventur ya agregué la entidad, y en la bd  esta como DATA_TYPE --  Date, Nullable -- YES,  DATA_DEFAULT --- (null)

Comment: Intenta agregar la siguiente anotación a tu campo Date :  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)

Comment: ya lo agregué pero me sale lo mismo

Comment: se que en tu db ya lo acepta como nulo pero probaste indicándole que la columna puede ser nula desde el entity?   @Column(nullable = true)

Comment: Ya mi agregué pero tampoco funciona , probé usando el método save de Jpa y si permite el null, pero me obliga a actualizar todos los campos y yo solo quiero los que puse en el query

Comment: Porqué cuando uso el método save si lo hace y con el query que puse no lo hace.?

Comment: Y si usas un método de JPA para actualizar, sin usar un query nativo, es decir :     void updateControlById(String cveEstado, String hora, Date fecha, String id);

Comment: @Ventur o sea sería quitar sólo la propiedad de nativeQuery=true?